# Error.. [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, postgresql

These are my codes.

index.ts

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core"
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";

const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);

    const post = orm.em.create(Post, {title: "my first post"});
    await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post);
    console.log("--------------sql2---------------");
    await orm.em.nativeInsert(Post, {title:"my first Post 2"});
};

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

mikro-orm.config.ts

```
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path";


export default {
    migrations: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './migrations'), // path to the folder with migrations
        pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // regex pattern for the migration files
    },
    entities: [Post],
    dbName: "lireddit",
    type: "postgresql",
    debug: !__prod__,
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

When I executed this commend, I got this error

```
npx mikro-orm migration:create

--> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Then I tried to fix this error by adding this in package.json, but then, I got a new error...

```
"type": "module",

--> [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\forgit\fullstack-practice\src\mikro-orm.config.ts
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8
The code is exactly same as in this video... ( ~ 32:00 )

But on my computer, it doesn't work..

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Create a minimal reproduction case. Your code doesn't even compile, so why are there 20+ lines of it? Write "hello world" first, get *that* compiled and running, then build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the node version is faulty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).